# Route specific docker internet from specific interface

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some docker containers and some network interfaces.

Like following image:
[image: diagram]

Every interface has one static public internet IP and Docker container has private bridge network (subnet: 172.17.0.0.0/24 and gateway: 17.17.0.1)

At now when I request to the internet from every of containers, request rout with interface 1(xxx.xxx.xxx.1)

problem: 
How can i route like this:

```
container 1 send request from interface1(IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.1)
container 2 send request from interface2(IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.2)
container 3 send request from interface3(IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.3)
container 4 send request from interface4(IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.4)
```